# Why was this question closed as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I was in the process of answering the question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831193/surakarta-board-game-capturing-pieces-move-generator

when it was suddenly closed as "too broad". I don't see why? The question asks how a program can enumerate the possible moves in a particular board game, whose rules were given by wikipedia link. OP additionally specified that it was the "loops" he was having trouble with ("loops" refer to the curved lines on the game board).

As such, I find the problem statement clear and unambiguous, and I was about the demonstrate that it can be correctly answered in a couple paragraphs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why shouldn't this question be closed as "too broad"?

Comment: Because the close reason does not apply? There are neither "too many possible answers", nor would "answers be too long for this format".

Comment: `Anyone here know a good algorithm ?` is very broad. There are many algorithms, and "good algorithms" would take an explanation on why it's good, how it can be applied, et cetera. Long answers would be long for this format as it takes the explanation. While it is true that the problem statement is clear, the problem itself is broad.

Comment: If the OP is capable of reducing that code-dump to a minimal verifiable example that question could be fine. As it is now it more reads as a *complete my code with these requirements*... that is too broad.

Comment: @Unihedron: I see. My reading of the question was that the OP was after a working and reasonably simple algorithm, not the very best (for some definition of "best") algorithm for the problem. After all, he currently has no working algorithm and the problem is so simple that it doesn't require any kind of optimization. That said, perhaps I was too liberal in my interpretation.

Answer (score 9):

I was the first person to vote to close this question. At the time, it only had a problem description: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25831193/1
It basically just said "Here's a Wikipedia article, how do I implement this?" The actual problem description wasn't even in the question itself.

The OP has now edited their question, but the edit is mostly a dump of code. It's not clear where the OP got stuck, trying to implement the algorithm.

In it's current form, I would be inclined to either leave the question alone, or VTC as "Unclear what you're asking". For now, I am going to leave it alone.

Comment: OP did write "Currently now i'm stuck on how the pieces can eat each other. The loops that make me stuck here.", so his question is not about the entire article, but only about the loop around the corner in the capturing moves.

Comment: I agree that the dump of code is not helpful, and in fact detracts from the question. But that dump occured after the question got closed, an in response to a "what have you tried" comment.

Comment: @meriton I think that question can be salvaged with some guidance and editing.